# java web app and xslt - what happens when xml/xslt files get changed?

Tags: java, jsp, xslt, spring-mvc

Trying to pickup on xslt I've been playing with some of it [here](http://markbucayan.appspot.com/xslt/index.html)

I'm curious as to what happens on the server side when I make a change to a xslt file (changing order of display or 2 divs for example)?
If I have a Spring view that uses that xslt, I make a change and reload the page int the browser, what happens then? When that xslt gets parsed/interpreted is there re-compiloation taking place? Is that process easier/harder on the server than dealing with a pure jsp view all other things being equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a change to the XSLT, it depends on three factors:

- Cache-control
- XSLT Processor
- Spring Interface

If the cache has not expired, nothing is recompiled and nothing changes.

If the cache has expired, then the Spring view resolver triggers the XSLT processor to reparse the XML data source when the page reloads

If the Spring Interface is not using [precompiled stylesheets](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-jaxp2/#N10277), then the stylesheet is recompiled